# how to add additional data in message asmack/smack?

Tags: android, message, smack, asmack

I am sending a message with (a)Smack and Openfire server. I am successfully able to send message with the message body. Now i need to send some additional data with the message. I don't want to append the string to the data and then process it after receiving. Is there any other approach? or with extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom [PacketExtension](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/PacketExtension.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use setProperty and getProperty method.

At sending end:

```
Message msg=new Message("jid", Message.Type.chat);
msg.setProperty("key", "value");
connection.sendMessage(msg);
```

At receiving end:

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    packetListner=new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

            Message message = (Message) packet;
            String myData=message.getProperty("key").toString();
        }
    };
    connection.addPacketListener(packetListner, filter);
```

Comment: You should add some more information - especially how this would look like and what is the advantage compared with the accepted answer.

Comment: I have no knowledge of smack - so I can't decide if your answer is correct. But it is a usually a sign of low quality if an answer consists only of one sentence - and thats why your answer was in the low quality queue for review. Now the significance of your answer is much higher and I think it would help someone who has the same problem.

Comment: Actually i was put answer first time on stack overflow, next time i will keep this thing in mind while answering

Comment: Message doesn't have get/setProperty method, use extensions instead as specific in Flow's answer